# NSNumber stores zero value instead of the correct numeric value

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I developing a simple calculator iPhone application. Just for practicing purpose. I have an IBAction method that stores the digits that the user entered. The whole concept is that the calculator app piles up pending oprations so the user can perform multiple actions and the screen shows the result the following way: 1 + 2 - 4 + 10 = X. So i have two NSMutableArray that stores  NSNumber numbers and the operator actions. When the user clicks an operator button, a new array element created for the new number. When the users entering the digits, the last array element is updating itself until an operator button is pressed.

The problem is that every array element is zero. Inside the method it stores the corrent value when i set it, but when the method is executed and called again it contins nothing but zeros instead of the entered numbers. The NSNumber objects are present, the array contains every number, but every number is 0.

Here is the method:

```
// Processing digit buttons 
- (IBAction)clickDigit: (UIButton *) sender {

    double currentNumber = [[numbers lastObject] doubleValue];

    // Get the digit
    double digit = sender.tag;

    // Do nothing when the currentNumber and the digit both zero
    if(currentNumber == 0 && digit == 0) {
        return;
    }

    // When currentNumber is zero, override the value
    if(currentNumber == 0) {

        currentNumber = digit;

        [numbers removeLastObject];
        [numbers addObject: [NSNumber numberWithDouble: currentNumber ]];

    // Else, add the digit to currentNumber
    } else {

        currentNumber = currentNumber * 10 + digit;

        [numbers removeLastObject];
        [numbers addObject: [NSNumber numberWithDouble: currentNumber ]];
    }

    // Update the screen
    [self updateDisplay];
}
```

I have no clue what's wrong. Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance

**UPDATE**: it turns out that the clickClear method is automatically called after each button press. It sets the value zero. I linked the full source code below this post in the comment section. The only question is: why this method called? What calls this method?

**UPDATE2**: with  The Saad's help i managed to solve this problem. Thanks to everyone! :)

Comment: Where do you create `numbers`? Is there any other code that accesses (especially modifies) `numbers`? If so, please post it.

Comment: I created it in the default ViewController and sets its default value in the viewDidLoad method. There is no other method that modifies numbers. Here is the full interface and implementation code. Note that it is incomple at the moment.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/tprwsd14 and http://pastebin.com/yb5YtAhE

Comment: A) Does `numbers` actually exist?  (The code shown will seem to work if `numbers` is nil, only zeros will be returned.)  B) Have you verified (eg, with NSLog) that `sender.tag` is actually returning what you think it should?  C) What have you done to debug this, on the whole?  It's not complex code, and debugging should be straight-forward.

Comment: What Hot Licks said. Also, have you tried putting brackets in the first `if` statement?

Comment: A) I defined numbers in the default ViewController as an NSMutabe pointer. The links above shows that. B) Sender.tag is contains the corrent digit, i tested it. C) I tested that the corrent values are returned and corretly stored in numbers. But i have no clue how to test why numbers contains zeros after the method execution.

Comment: Are you using ARC? Some other things that might cause trouble: You are doing a lot of implicit conversions between ints and doubles. And your if statements are comparing doubles with ints (0), I'm not sure if this is even well defined.

Answer (score 1):

The only possible way you get this problem is if `sender.tag == 0` all the time. So you should definitely check that. My point here is that there is not other possible scenario that produces those symptoms, so it has to be it.

Comment: I tested  it with breakpoints and NSLog calls. It contains the corrent digit. I think the reason is could be similar that Hot Licks said, somehow the objects are destoyed or may be the "numbers" creation is wrong. However, the array contains the numbers, so the objects are present, but all values are zero. Again, the sender.tag returns the correct value. And when i added it to the NSMutableArray it shows the corrent value. But when this method called again, the number become zero.

Answer (score 0):

ok got it,

one thing here is that first check your sender's tag, either by braekpoint or by NSLog in click Digit method, i guess tags never gets up than zero, and hence the last object in array will always be zero, further, place nslog or breakpoint on all places where you are adding object to array.

in interface.

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray* numberArray;
```

in implementation,

```
@synthesize numberArray = _numberArray;
```

in dealloc

```
[_numberArray release];
```

ok now next thing is to make an array in init which is

```
NSMutableArray* arr = [NSMutableArray alloc] init];
self.numberArray = arr;
[arr release];

[self.numberArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:0]];
```

Comment: I tested  it with breakpoints and NSLog calls. It contains the corrent digit. I think the reason is could be similar that Hot Licks said, somehow the objects are destoyed or may be the "numbers" creation is wrong. However, the array contains the numbers, so the objects are present, but all values are zero. Again, the sender.tag returns the correct value. And when i added it to the NSMutableArray it shows the corrent value. But when this method called again, the number become zero.

Comment: akha, you are rite, your array memory is not propery allocated. i 'm editing answer, use edit code at the end and tell me if you find any solution

Comment: he does allocate (edit: and init!) the array in viewDidLoad(), which should be fine.

Comment: memory allocation is another thing, it may be that when you addobjects, the memory is not allocated to array, and then whenever u addobject to it, it will not be mutable array but simple nsarray with all entries that are at last, and it is a good practice always to allocate memory in init methods

Comment: I tried this without any luck. Same symptoms. I did a little debugging. I removed the update method and i stores each digit. After the addition i lists the NSMutableArray contents. It shows that the digit are present in each execution as the last object, but anything else is become zero. Here it is: http://pastebin.com/FPk4ARXR

Comment: did you try what i said you about memory management of array? i.e. using with property

Comment: Yes. Also i think i found the problem. I using Automatic Reference Counter. You wrote such a code that i assumed you dont use that feature. I tried without it. I got some error messages in the clickClear method. It looks like this method called after each button press. So it sets the value 0. The only problem is i dont know why this method called. I wasnt associated it with these buttons. How can i break the associations? Or what calls that?

Comment: go to xib file, rite clike the button, there will be the connection in greyed out, with a little cross sign clik that, it will be released,

Comment: Got it, thanks. I did not know how this is happened. May i have some questions? Im novice in Objective-C and the Cocoa(Touch) frameworks. Should i use Automatic Reference Counting or not? What the differences between Stroyboard and the Xib format. What should i use? Thanks in advance.

Comment: and best thing i suggest for u not to use ARC neither Story board, first get the basic things, story board is you work on all the screen at the same time, while in xib, you manage it most of time programetically